# Accuracy of integer sqrt using double

Tags: floating-point, square-root

I would like to compute the integer part of an `uint64_t`. For 32-bit `uint32_t`, it is frequently recommended to first cast it to `double`, `sqrt` and then cast it back to `uint32_t`.

Does it work for `uint64_t` as well, given that `double` can exactly accommodate numbers only up to 2^53? I.e., is the following always going to give the correct answer:

```
#include <math.h>
uint64_t x = ...;
uint64_t result = (uint64_t)sqrt((double)x);
```

or even:

```
#include <math.h>
uint64_t x = ...;
uint32_t result = (uint32_t)sqrt((double)x);
```

Comment: Even for `uint32_t`, this is only reliable if you know your math library’s `sqrt` is good and your C implementation is good with floating-point operations. The C standard alone does not require this. Some math libraries return only approximate results even for values that have representable exact square roots.

Comment: I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15212684/1798593) recommending the double strategy for 32 bit integer, but it was in response to a Java question. The answer depended on Java-specific guarantees, and is not applicable to C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empirically, the answer is **no**.  The result for an input of 4503599761588224 is computed incorrectly as 67108865 rather than 67108864.

The following code identifies this case.<sup>1</sup>  Of course, you can remove the `break;` to observe other cases.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    for (uint32_t y = 1; y != 0; y++) {
        // *Just* smaller than a perfect square
        uint64_t x = ((uint64_t)y * (uint64_t)y) - 1;

        // We expect the floor of the result     
        uint32_t expected = y - 1;

        uint32_t result = (uint32_t)sqrt((double)x);

        if (result != expected) {
            printf("Incorrect: x = %llu, result = %u\n", x, result);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What's special about the value 4503599761588224?  Well, it's exactly (2<sup>26</sup> + 1)<sup>2</sup> - 1, AKA (2<sup>52</sup> + 2<sup>27</sup>).  This can be exactly represented by a `double`, so the error is not due to the `long` -> `double` conversion.

Instead, the error is internal to the `sqrt` implementation.  The delta (vs. a perfect square) here reduces the square root by around 2<sup>-27</sup>, which is around 2<sup>53</sup> times smaller than `result` itself.  This is at the limit of what double-precision can handle, so we would naturally expect to see off-by-one errors at this point.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sub>1. [Live demo](https://ideone.com/q6jglX).</sub>

<sub>2. Credit to @EricPostpischil for identifying the root cause in comments below :)</sub>

Comment: Of course, if we are given that the math library is good and returns a correctly rounded square root, then we know the result is close and can easily test and correct it with integer arithmetic.

Comment: The reason the failure occurs at 2\*\*26 is the derivative of sqrt(x) is 1/(2\*sqrt(x)). So, at (2\*\*26)**2, subtracting one reduces the square root by about 2\*\*-27. And the square root is just under 2\*\*26, so the reduction is about 2\*\*-53 times the square root, so you have just hit the edge of double precision.

Comment: Even if the math library is only very approximately correct, one could bracket the square root and do a binary search.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Nice explanation.  I've incorporated this into my answer (with credits to you!).